# How to break down a large document into small documents based on a pattern using Regex?

Tags: python, regex

The large document consists of small document separated by pattern like "1 of 1435 DOCUMENTS". I want to break it down into 1435 small documents.

```
 re_1 =  r"\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS.+?"

 re_2 =  r"\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS.+"
```

re_1 gives me "1 of 1435 DOCUMENTS" etc only. 
re_2 gives me the entire doc.

If there a way using re.findall with a proper regex? 
or I have to do a re.split (which happens to be easiest for this case) or alternatively loops over each line and checks for the pattern?  Thank you!

```
1 of 1435 DOCUMENTS
blabla (multiple lines)

2 of 1435 DOCUMENTS
blabla(multiple lines)
3 of 1435 DOCUMENTS
blabla(multiple lines)
4 of 1435 DOCUMENTS
blabla(multiple lines)

5 of 1435 DOCUMENTS
....
```

Comment: You may use `re.split(r'(?!\A)(?=^\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS)', text, flags=re.M)` with Python 3.7

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With earlier versions of Python prior to 3.7 you can use `re.findall` with

```
r'(?sm)^\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS.*?(?=^\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS|\Z)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pzQZGg/3)

**Details**

- `(?sm)` - `re.M` and `re.S` options on
- `^` - start of the line
- `\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS` - 1 to 4 digits, space, `of`, space, 1 to 4 digits, space and `DOCUMENTS` substring
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars, as few as possible up to the closest
- `(?=^\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS|\Z)` - `^\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS` pattern or (`|`) the end of the string (`\Z`).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/E7R6Yq):

```
import re
s = "TEXT_HERE"
print(re.findall(r'^\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS.*?(?=\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS|\Z)', s, re.M | re.S))
# => ['1 of 1435 DOCUMENTS\nblabla (multiple lines)\n\n', '2 of 1435 DOCUMENTS\nblabla(multiple lines)\n', '3 of 1435 DOCUMENTS\nblabla(multiple lines)\n', '4 of 1435 DOCUMENTS\nblabla(multiple lines)\n\n', '5 of 1435 DOCUMENTS\n....']
```

With Python 3.7, where `re.split` can split with zero length matches you may use

```
r'(?m)(?!\A)(?=^\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pzQZGg/2).

**Details**

- `(?m)` - `re.M` option is on
- `(?!\A)` - not at the start of the string
  -`(?=^\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS)` - immediately to the right, there must be start of a line, 1 to 4 digits, space, `of`, space, 1 to 4 digits, space and `DOCUMENTS` substring

Usage:

```
re.split(r'(?!\A)(?=^\d{1,4} of \d{1,4} DOCUMENTS)', text, flags=re.M)
```